# How to add multiple lines from a TMemo component to a MS Access database?

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-2010, memo, tadoquery

I got an ADO Database with a table named `t_codemeaning`, below are the table structure :

```
t_codemeaning
  codemenaing_code AS Text
  codemenaing_title AS Text
  codemenaing_description AS Text
```

I add all of table in my `ADOQuery1`.

I click a button with this Delphi script:

```
ADOQuery1.edit;
ADOQuery1codemeaning_title.value := edit1.text;  
ADOQuery1codemeaning_description.value := memo1.lines.text;  
ADOQuery1.post;
```

When I add the single line in memo, then every thing is Fine.

But when I add lot of multiple line of text in memo1, then it shows me an error :

> **Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value.**

How to fix this ?

---

My last progress, I made a new string variable aValue and add the memo1.lines.text into it  :

```
  aValue:=memo1.lines.text;
  aValue := StringReplace(StringReplace(aValue, '#10', '', [rfReplaceAll]), '#13', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

And I change the script for ADOQuery1codemeaning_description.value ....  into :

```
ADOQuery1codemeaning_description.value := aValue;
```

still got the same error...

Comment: This is caused by the "CRLF" line endings in your code. When you assign the lines it gets encoded as one string. You need to escape the line endings in the format expected by the ADO machine. In other words, the multi-line memo string is passing invalid characters to the ADO.

Comment: does "CRLF" refer to #13#10 ?

Comment: aValue:=memo1.lines.text;

  aValue := StringReplace(StringReplace(aValue, '#10', '', [rfReplaceAll]), '#13', '', [rfReplaceAll]);

Comment: Yes. On Linux it is just LF or #10 but windows uses the #13#10 but many programs in windows also understand plain #10. Double check the format expected by the ADO function. At best do exactly what you specified in previous commect yes! That should work. Maybe replace with the space character?

Comment: And still got the same error....

Comment: Do not put the #13 inside the string. I mean the parameter to the function, just put #13#10 as the parameter, and do not put it in quotes. As for StringReplace you can call it twice with #10 as well is more portable code or just do it for #13#10 once which is fine for windows.

Comment: What DB you use? The description field probably needs to be a type of `Memo`. and your persistent `ADOQuery1codemeaning_description` field type should be `ftMemo` not `ftString`. There is no need to escape anything.

Comment: aValue:=mmDescription1.lines.text; aValue := StringReplace(StringReplace(aValue, #10, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]), #13, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);

Comment: I use ADO / Access Database Object (.MDB) with JET OLEDB connection

Comment: ahh... Kobik, you are right.... the mistake is at the type of the table structure for the field : codemenaing_description AS Text. It should be defined as codemenaing_description AS Memo.... Done all of the matter is cleared :) 

Do you mind to post your answer ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define your `description` field as `Memo` in the DB (instead of `Text`), and then remove all your persistent fields from `ADOQuery1`, and add them again so that `ADOQuery1codemeaning_description` type is `ftMemo`.

No need to escape or replace `CRLF`.